# HttpClient request i am getting !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC

Tags: c#, httpclient

I need to make a request, here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://rgwspublic2/RgWsPublic2" xmlns:ns2="http://rgwspublic2/RgWsPublic2Service" xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<env:Header>
<ns1:Security>
<ns1:UsernameToken>
<ns1:Username>xxxx</ns1:Username>
<ns1:Password>xxxx</ns1:Password>
</ns1:UsernameToken>
</ns1:Security>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
<ns2:rgWsPublic2AfmMethod>
<ns2:INPUT_REC>
<ns3:afm_called_by/>
<ns3:afm_called_for>xxxx</ns3:afm_called_for>
</ns2:INPUT_REC>
</ns2:rgWsPublic2AfmMethod>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

and Here is how i am trying to make the request

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
        soapEnvelopeXml.Load("C:\\REQUESTSOAP.xml");
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var httpContent = new StringContent(GetXMLAsString(soapEnvelopeXml), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
            var result =await client.PostAsync("https://www1.gsis.gr:443", httpContent);
            var answer =await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(answer.ToString());
        }
    }
    public string GetXMLAsString(XmlDocument myxml)
    {
        return myxml.OuterXml;
    }
```

Unfortunately i am getting this error

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.gsis.gr"></HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

How can i fix this problem? Should i use webRequest instead HttpClient. Also can i send it as json?

Comment: Hi, what is the http status code?

Comment: Hello Stefan, my status code is 200.